# Cypress: test if element exists

Tags: if-statement, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am new to cypress, I know that this question has been asked before but I am still stuck here!
This is the what I have written:

```js
 it("User can set certification for multiple users at once",()=>{
       cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .RadioButton__StyledRadioButton-sc-1j2qp2u-1').click(); //clicking Non-certified button
       const $el=Cypress.$('[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU"]');
       cy.get("body").then($body =>{
        if ($body.find($el.length>0)) {
         cy.log('in if loop');
         cy.log($el.length);
         cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
         cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
        } else {
        cy.log('in else loop');
        cy.log($el.length);
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
      }
     })
    })
```

But when the element `$el` is not found (and it logs `$el.length=0` which is correct), it still tries to execute the if loop, whereas it should be in else loop...any ideas on how to resolve this?Thanks!

So I updated my code again because this condition `($body.find($el.length>0))` always evaluates to true as rightly pointed out by Richard Matsen. What happens now is that it calculates the length to be 0, and therefore enters else loop, but I can see the element on the web page and still it gets the length as 0..what is the reason and what can I do about it?

```js
it("User can set certification for multiple users at once",()=>{
       cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .RadioButton__StyledRadioButton-sc-1j2qp2u-1').click(); //clicking Non-certified button
       const $el=Cypress.$('[class="Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU"]');
       cy.get("body").then($body =>{
        if ($body.find($el).length>0) {
         cy.log('in if loop');
         cy.log($body.find($el).length);
         cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
         cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
        } else if($body.find($el).length==0){
        cy.log('in else loop');
        cy.log($body.find($el).length);
        cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
        cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
      }
   })
 })
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `$el.length>0` in `$body.find()`? It returns a jQuery object and therefore always evaluates to truthy.

Comment: hmm, I understood your point, Thanks Richard! So I have updated my code in the edit. What happens now is that it prints the length as 0, and is therefore in the else loop, but the element does exist, I see it on the web page but its getting the length as 0; it should be getting the length 1 and therefore execute the if loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this:

```js
it("User can set certification for multiple users at once",()=>{
    cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .RadioButton__StyledRadioButton-sc-1j2qp2u-1').click(); //clicking Non-certified button
    const selector=".Typography__StyledTypography-sc-153d8g4-0.jhYDmS.TrainingQueueListstyles__EmptyListMessage-sc-19yfim3-1.ihRiqU";
    cy.get("body").then($body =>{
        const $el = $body.find(selector);
        if ($el) {
            cy.log('in if loop');
            cy.get('.hZDZBR').should('not.exist');
            cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').should('not.exist');
        } else {
            cy.log('in else loop');
            cy.get('input[id="selectAll"]').click();
            cy.get('.hZDZBR').click();
        }
    })
})
```

The few changes I've made are:

- Use a selector rather than querying the initial element
- Query the actual element in your callback
- If/Else based on that result

Comment: Thanks, but not working:(  I am also printing the `$el` in the blocks just for verification. What it does is, it doesnt find the `$el` and correctly prints it as `{ }` but then remains in if block, if `$el` is empty, it should go to else block but doesnt...I just dont understand how to go about this...