# Cypress contains statement in if/else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, automated-tests, cypress

I am writing a code block to monitor a dialogbox and its contents.
I've written a while loop which will track some activity progress, wherein there is status value as

> "Status : In Progress"

and which when the progress completes changes to

> "Status: Completed".

inside while loop, I've written an if/else block

```
while(true)
{

    if(cy.get('<locator>').contains('progress',{matchCase:false}))
    {
        statements
    }
    else
    {
        statements
    }
}
```

Here the while loop executes repeatedly until the "Status : In Progress" value is present,

i.e. the if condition becomes true, but when progress completes and status changes to "Completed" it fails and raises AssertionError, and stops the test case without entering the else block.

I have some statements which are required to be executed when if condition fails, and instead of returning AssertionError control should go to the else block.

How do I do that ?

Comment: you can probably find an example in related discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60422516/cypress-test-if-element-exists?rq=1

Comment: I think you need to use a then block for this to work, https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice guide on [conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition) in Cypress docs. When it comes to your example, I assume something like this could do the trick:

```
while(true)
{
    // Get the element first and use .then() command to proceed with it
    cy.get('<locator>').then(($btn) => {

          // assert on the text
          if ($btn.text().includes('progress')) {
               // do your statements
          } else {
               // do other statements
          }
  })
}
```

Or something similar. I hope that's helpful!

Comment: I've noticed that if I use 'while(true)', the test case hangs on the it block

Comment: Also, how do i break from the while loop when 'else' block gets executed

Comment: @philein-sophos `break;`